# Design for membership of a group

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation, table

I have two different databases. One of these is a Users table, and another is a Groups table.

A group can have multiple users, and a user can have multiple groups

What's the best way to associate a user with a group? I see some options:

- Store a list of **users** in the **Group** and store no list of groups for the user.
- Store a list of **groups** in the **User** and store no list of users for the group.
- Store **both** a list of users for each Group, as well as a list of groups for each user.

What are the pros and cons of each design? I think the 3rd option is the worst as it requires synchronization work, and duplicates data.

Comment: Even though this smells like homework... the best way is to have a UserGroup table that has UserID/GroupID as a link table. You have a many-to-many situation, creating an intermediate table to store the relationship resolves the situation by "reversing the crows feet" on your ERD.

Comment: > "Even though this smells like homework". It's not

Comment: If you have the option of changing technology a graph DBMS would excel at this kind of thing.

Comment: If you're looking for a NoSQL approach edit the question to make that very clear.

Answer (score 1):

> A group can have multiple users, and a user can have multiple groups

It's called a many-to-many relationship. Relationally, there is only one way to store that and that's with a linking-table,

```
CREATE TABLE users ( userid int PRIMARY KEY, name_user text );
CREATE TABLE groups ( groupid int PRIMARY KEY, name_group text );
CREATE TABLE user_group (
  userid  int REFERENCES users,
  groupid int REFERENCES groups,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid, groupid)
);
```

Any other way you store that you'll lose relational integrity.

Comment: Thanks - this looks good for SQL. What about a NoSQL database like Elasticsearch?

Comment: I think reversing the order of the PRIMARY KEY to (groupid, userid) may be more beneficial since normally a group has a lot of members, but a user does not belong to that many groups. So querying by groupid will be faster by reversing the order. Or you can create a separate index on groupid. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048154/indexes-and-multi-column-primary-keys)

Comment: @Rich it sounds more useful to know what groups a specific user is in, then what users are in a group.

Comment: Yeah, It depends on the application for sure. In a group fanout scenario, the app may be interested in all the members belong to a group.